# Почему так произошло Warning: session_start(): Failed to read session data: user

Tags: php

Почему так произошло

```
( ! ) Warning: session_start(): Failed to read session data: user (path: /var/lib/php/sessions)
in /var/www/php.xxx/session/handlers.php on line 73
Call Stack
#  Time    Memory  Function           Location
1  0.0003  395424  {main}( )          .../handlers.php:0
2  0.0003  395832  session_start ( )  .../handlers.php:73
```

Если убрать `session_start();` то ошибка пропадает

```
<?php ## Переопределение обработчиков сессии.
  // Возвращает полное имя файла временного хранилища сессии.
  // В случае, если нужно изменить тот каталог, в котором должны 
  // храниться сессии, достаточно поменять только эту функцию
  function ses_fname($key)
  {
    return dirname(__FILE__)."/sessiondata/".session_name()."/$key"; 
  }
  // Заглушки - эти функции просто ничего не делают
  function ses_open($save_path, $ses_name)
  {
    return true;
  }
  function ses_close()
  {
    return true;
  }

  // Чтение данных из временного хранилища
  function ses_read($key)
  {
    // Получаем имя файла и открываем файл.
    $fname = ses_fname($key);
    return @file_get_contents($fname);
  }

  // Запись данных сессии во временное хранилище
  function ses_write($key, $val)
  {
    $fname = ses_fname($key);
    // Сначала создаем все каталоги (в случае, если они уже есть,
    // игнорируем сообщения об ошибке)
    @mkdir(dirname(dirname($fname)), 0777);
    @mkdir(dirname($fname), 0777);
    // Создаем файл и записываем в него данные сессии.
    @file_put_contents($fname, $val);
    return true;
  }

  // Вызывается при уничтожении сессии
  function ses_destroy($key)
  {
    return @unlink(ses_fname($key));
  }

  // Сборка мусора - ищем все старые файлы и удаляем их
  function ses_gc($maxlifetime)
  {
    $dir = ses_fname(".");
    // Получаем доступ к каталогу текущей группы сессии.
    foreach (glob("$dir/*") as $fname) {
      // Файл слишком старый?
      if (time() - filemtime($fname) >= $maxlifetime) {
        @unlink($fname);
        continue;
      }
    }
    // Если директория непуста, она не удалится - будет предупреждение.
    // Мы его подавляем. Если же пуста - удалится, что нам и нужно.
    @rmdir($dir);
    return true;
  }

  // Регистрируем наши новые обработчики
  session_set_save_handler(
    "ses_open", "ses_close", 
    "ses_read", "ses_write", 
    "ses_destroy", "ses_gc"
  );

  // Для примера подключаемся к группе сессий test.
  session_name("test1");
  session_start();
  // Увеличиваем счетчик в сессии.
  $_SESSION['count'] = @$_SESSION['count'] + 1;
?>
<h2>Счетчик</h2>
В текущей сессии работы с браузером Вы открыли эту страницу
<?=$_SESSION['count']?> раз(а).<br>
Закройте браузер, чтобы обнулить счетчик.<br>
<a href="<?=$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']?>" target="_blank">Открыть дочернее окно браузера</a>.
```

Comment: А что у Вас там не нравится в 73 строке? И версия php какая ?

Comment: PHP Version 7.2.24

Comment: session_start(); ненравится

Comment: причем тут path: /var/lib/php/sessions

Comment: Он пишет, что не может прочитать данные сессии в файле handlers.php on line 73. Думается, пока не сможет прочитать, то и ошибка будет, потому как с 7.1.0  session_start() теперь возвращает FALSE и больше не инициализирует $_SESSION, когда она не смогла запустить сессию.

Comment: не очень понятно. объясните по простому

Comment: Вам нужно постараться разобраться с ошибкой - смотрите, что там в каждой проблемной строке, когда высвечиваться будет - Вы можете код запускать, а здесь только гадать можно.

Comment: я когда убрал пропала ошибка. скажите что делать

Comment: Посмотрите мануал - лучше не подскажешь - пересказ хуже https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.session-name.php и https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.session-start.php. Когда Вы убираете session_start, то сессии просто нет - session_name некуда передавать что, потому это и не вызывает ошибку - ничего нет, потому и ошибки нет.

Comment: это понятно. как убрать ошибку и почему она возникает,?

Comment: Вы можете запускать код и смотреть, что к чему - попробуйте поставить точки останова и посмотрите.

Comment: адрес не тот который должен выполняться в коде

Answer (score 0):

Это пример из книги PHP7. В подлиннике.
Нашел ошибку. Проблема в функции ses_read.
При первом запуске данного файла не существует. В этом случае функция возвращает 0 и сессия закрывается. Нам же нужно, чтобы функция ses_read возвращала пустую строку, если нет данных. Переписал функцию так:

```
function ses_read($key){
// Получаем имя файла и открываем файл
    $fname = ses_fname($key);
    $str = @file_get_contents($fname);
    return $str ? $str:"";
}
```

И все заработало.